# gcc:cannot find -lpython2.7 when including python headers during linking

Tags: python, c, gcc, mingw

I am trying to port python codes on windows to c codes and the convert it to an executable on **windows 7**. In linux I can do this easily, but in windows, this is totally new for me plus I am not good with compilers.

I download minGW and installed the compiler collection which includes gcc.

Below shows how I am trying to include python headers when compiling the .c file

```
C:\Users\repzero>gcc -Os -I C:\Python27\include  -o C:\Users\repzero\hello.o C:\Users\repzero\hello.c -lpython2.7 -lpthread -lm -lutil
```

I get the errors

```
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/5.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lpython2.7
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/5.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lutil
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

**Additional information**

Here is my command line which I used to port python codes to c does (This generates hello.c) **this works fine**

```
cython --embed -o hello.c hello.py
```

How can I alleviate those errors?

Comment: "during compilation" is misleading because it's clearly a linker error

Comment: @Stargateur I can download it and try it...have you tried with it with including python?..just a thought..

Comment: ld didn't find python2 and util library you should add `-L path_to_python_lib -L path_to_util_lib`

Comment: @Fang..I will edited question heading

Comment: @repzero with python, it would ask to config cmakelist with python. It's could be hard indeed. It was just saying, in my experience compile on windows with gcc is really painful. I prefer use visual studio on windows and gcc/clang on linux with a good cmake to generate project configuration.

Comment: @Stargateur I will try this with visual studio in the meantime....I appreciate the tip